# Building android gives me "*** No rule to make target `/.txt' .." (Rest in description)

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source

Building AOSP gives me this:

> *** No rule to make target '/.txt', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-cm-last-timestamp'. 
>   Stop.

The device i am building for is my Moto G 213 (falcon), and the device list is from Cyanogenmod. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. I think I may have found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731304/how-to-fix-this-api-error)

```
make update-api && make
```

or equivalently for Android

```
mka update-api && mka
```

But after this command I got the following error:

> Error after mka: build/core/package_internal.mk:276: recipe for target
>   '/home/weber/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk'
>   failed

I don't know if it is related.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was just forgetting to select device on launch.